# Addplot color based on value

Tags: tikz-pgf

i would like to assign a color range for addplot. This is my example:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[xmin=0.0, xmax = 1.0, ymin=-0.0003, ymax=0.3, width=7.8cm, label={Normalized Vector Magnitude}, ylabel={Density}]
 \addplot[color=red] %here should be a range instead 
  coordinates{
  (0.0, 0.1)
  (0.1, 0.2)
  (0.2, 0.3)
  (0.3, 0.2)
  (0.4, 0.1)
  (0.5, 0.15)
  (0.6, 0.2)
  (0.7, 0.22)
  (0.8, 0.23)
  (0.9, 0.2)
  (1.0, 0.0)
 };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

So i would like to map the x-values-range to a color range like the hue value from the [hsv-model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV). The color should change continously on this range. Is there a possibility?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Now there is a working example, sorry

Comment: If you put `[mesh,point meta=x]` instead of `[color=red]` does that come closer to what you ask?

Comment: A tip for you: search in the manual of the `pgfplots` package, there are some examples.

Comment: @percusse this helps BUT i need a certain color range from the mentioned hsv-model. This means that the mapping is defined as [0,1]->[0,360], where the target is the hue value

Comment: with this coarse granularity (few samples) you cannot do that. A single segment of the plot cannot change any color. Once you have enough samples you can create a colormap as given in the manual.

Comment: You can map [0,1] to [0,1000.0] by setting `point meta min=0` and `point meta max=1`. From [0,1000.0] to color you probability need `scatter/@pre marker code/.code` or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the manual by the help of comments, i came to this solution fitting my needs:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{
 colormap={blackwhite}{[5pt]
    rgb255(0pt)=(255, 0, 0);
    rgb255(500pt)=(255, 255, 0);
    rgb255(500pt)=(255, 255, 0);
    rgb255(1000pt)=(0, 255, 0 );
    rgb255(1000pt)=(0, 255, 0 );
    rgb255(1500pt)=(0, 0, 255);
    rgb255(1500pt)=(0, 0, 255);
    rgb255(2000pt)=(255, 0, 255);
    rgb255(2000pt)=(255, 0, 255);
    rgb255(2500pt)=(255,0,0)
 },
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[xmin=0.0, xmax = 1.0, ymin=-0.0003, ymax=0.3, width=7.8cm, label={Normalized Vector Magnitude}, ylabel={Density}]
 \addplot[mesh, point meta=explicit] %here should be a range instead 
  coordinates{
  (0.0, 0.1) [0]
  (0.1, 0.2) [1]
  (0.2, 0.3) [2]
  (0.3, 0.2) [3]
  (0.4, 0.1) [4]
  (0.5, 0.15) [5]
  (0.6, 0.2) [6]
  (0.7, 0.22) [7]
  (0.8, 0.23) [8]
  (0.9, 0.2) [9]
  (1.0, 0.0) [10]
 };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```